# Angular 9 Mat-Slider does not work properly on iOS Devices

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular9, mat-slider

**EDIT : 
On iOS 12.4.6 it still doesn't work, but at least the bar is not jumpy anymore, but still not registering the values, or unmute at pre-setted value of 20% .
On iOS 13.3.1 ( my other phone ) all the described problems reproduce**

I have a mat-slider inside my web application to control a video's volume that runs in the background.

On iOS ( Safari / Chrome ) , it doesn't respect any of my implementations that when the user unmutes video to jump to 20% ( It jumps to 100% however value is not registered, it still hears as 20% ) .

If I try to slide to any value, it jumps back to 100% by itself. With Taps and not Sliding it stays on the location but it's not registering the value ( the volume remains the same ) .

On Android devices / Desktop it works just as I want it to.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "taraful-turnenii-web-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 192.168.1.2",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod" : "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.29",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

CLI

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 9.1.1
Node: 13.13.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.1
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.1
@angular/cdk                      9.2.1
@angular/cli                      9.1.1
@angular/flex-layout              9.0.0-beta.29
@angular/material                 9.2.1
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.1
@schematics/angular               9.1.1
@schematics/update                0.901.1
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

HTML Code for mat-slider :

```
<mat-slider class="matSlider" 
  [value]="matBarValue"
  (input)="videoElement.volume = $event.value"
  (change)="changeBtnIcoWithSlider(videoElement, muteBtn)" tickInterval="0.01" step="0.01" min="0" max="1"></mat-slider>
```

CSS :

```
.mat-slider {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 17vw;
}

@media(max-width: 397px) {

  .mat-slider {
    margin-top: 3px;
    width: 200px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {

  .mat-slider {
    margin-top: 3px;
    width: 77vw;
  }

}
```

TS Code that is called within the slider

```
changeBtnIcoWithSlider(videoElement, muteBtn: HTMLButtonElement) {
    if (videoElement.volume > 0) {
      videoElement.muted = false;
      this.matBarValue = videoElement.volume;
      muteBtn.innerHTML = 'Mute Video'
      this.imageSrc = 'assets/VolIcon.png';
    } else {
      muteBtn.innerHTML = 'Unmute Video';
      this.imageSrc = 'assets/MuteIcon.png';
      videoElement.muted = true;
    }
  }
```

What I tried : Adding hammerjs however I read that is not mandatory for this version of angular in order for mat-slider to work with gesture recognition ( It works on android .. )

Placing the mat slider module import after , BrowserAnimationsModule and BrowserModule, also in between or above them as I saw these kind of orders helped others.

Nothing works.

Thank you .

Comment: Iam using Cordova and angular with lazy loading, The swipe is not working on the slider .Is that working for you ? if so could you please share some tips please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

It seems like on iOS you can't set the volume property via JS / TS and as Apple doc says :

```
On iOS devices, the audio level is always under the user’s physical control. The volume property is not settable in JavaScript. Reading the volume property always returns 1.
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW11